# deviceready has not fired in phonegap 2.9.0 with sencha touch 2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I use PhoneGap 2.9.0 and SenchaTouch to develop my Android application (targetSdkVersion 16).

When I start the app in Chrome, I got such logs :

```
Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only. cordova.js:912
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:6725
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova.js:6718
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady  cordova.js:6718
```

When I test it in Samsung tablet (Android 4.1.2), the first line disappeared but the 3 events are always not fired.

However, it seems SenchaTouch works quite good: views display and interactions works as I expect.

Here's the head section of index.html:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
       some css here
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="pg/cordova.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="pg/barcodescanner.js"></script>  

 </head>
```

I use some phonegap API such as Camera and File. As PhoneGap receives never deviceready event, the API is not available so navigator.camera is undefined.

I did a hug research but all I tested does not resolve the problem. Any advice is welcome
Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to log navigator.camera in lanch function of app.js, it was well defined. However, when I called it later, it became "undefined". My app is in a navigation view (I don't know if this matters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue, but in my case it was due to the fact that I have referenced plugins in my config.xml which I have  not instantiated within my application.

Simply commenting them out until I referenced them in my code gave me an immediate "Phonegap is ready".

Thanks goes to: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/deviceready_has_not_fired_after_5_seconds

Comment: May you elaborate more on your solution? I have exactly this problem but I cannot understand your solution.

Comment: It's a fairly old thread, so I hope it's still of use. My suggestion is to remove everything but the initial plugin from your confix.xml, and then see if it loads correctly. My error was due to adding additional elements within my xml, but not calling them within my app - so it seems to be stuck, waiting for the events to fire on page. Can you share some code?

Comment: I solved. The problem was the PhoneGap.js included twice by Sencha Touch micro loader, due to a misconfiguration and documentation unclear on this aspect

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try with a clean not-sencha html, just to trace if the error cames from sencha or phonegap

Comment: Could you please give more instructions ? I don't see how to set up a "not-sencha" html to test.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just an html example. Did you try the assets included in 'example'?

Comment: the example works, I received the event. I doubt whether the time to load Sencha Touch is too long. I tried to cordova.js before sencha's microloader: no event fired and I had a white screen..

Comment: I recommend to use the sencha cmd to generate the app and again to build it. Remember you should use sencha app build package, then cp the build/app/package to your android assets. Aditionally add the cordova.js in the app.json that way you dont touch anything at the index.html. Then, to make use of the 'ready event' you could add something in app.js::launch().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a hard-coded time out when loading urls. This time-out occurs because the size of the page, generated by Sencha Touch, can't be calculated. Unfortunately I can't find the resources I used to solve this problem in the past, so correct me if I'm wrong, but my solution was to create a html file with a redirect to the actual index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Launch the generated index.html file to prevent Cordova/PhoneGap timeouts -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>AppName</title>
    <script>
        window.location = './index.html';
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iOS 8 Beta 1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html) (WebKit section), it is a known issue that Cordova/Phonegap apps are currently broken due to a user agent bug.

Applying this temporary "fix" solved my issues with the "deviceready" event not being fired.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069550

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to include cordova plugin before closing of body tag, as follows
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src='cordova.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```