# Phonegap / Cordova not working in ios8

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8

I played around with the iOS 8 beta and noticed that Cordova/Phonegap is pretty much broken.

For me it is mainly the InAppBrowser that now doesn't show up.

what are your experiences?
Do you have a fix or an idea for a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Since it just came out today (in beta preview), and Cordova is an open source project: wait until the community posts about it. I'm sure in the coming months there will be a release that addresses any compatibility with iOS8. If you are seeing anything in particular, post an issue with Cordova/Phonegap directly to help them work through it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix this with a bit of Javascript in your index.html (or install iOS 8 beta 2, which seems to have fixed the issue):
https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cd02c73162180793513e#file-ios8-beta-phonegap-fix

```
// temp fix for iOS8 beta, add it after the reference to cordova.js
// You don't actually require it for ios 8 beta 5
if (navigator.userAgent === undefined) {
  navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() {
    return("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit");
  });
}
```

Comment: Official Cordova bug report [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6863). Fix: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-js.git;a=commitdiff;h=2ae3caa;hp=d970db70850a22b2001bc222f8ad6fff45a321fd

Comment: Seems to be fixed in iOS 8 beta 2 :)

Answer (score 7):

In early iOS 8 Betas, Cordova/Phonegap apps were broken due to a user agent bug, but according to the [iOS 8 Beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html) (WebKit section) this bug was officially fixed in iOS 8 Beta 3. (It was actually already fixed in iOS 8 Beta 2.)

Good to see that Apple has tested Cordova/Phonegap apps and fixed this issue.  A bit disappointing that the bug existed in the first place, but early betas always have lots of issues.

Comment: "Good to see that Apple has tested Cordova/Phonegap apps" Please. They probably wouldn't notice if the bug wasn't reported: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=128303 (it was, in fact, reported way before iOS 8 beta even shipped, but only got fixed with iOS 8 b2)

Comment: Also note that it was actually fixed in beta 2. The release notes are wrong :)

Comment: Quite right.  Have updated release notes section accordingly.  I was trying to give Apple the benefit of the doubt, but if they had actually done some Cordova testing, this is such a big error that it should have been fixed straight away. I'm still wrestling with some WebKit rendering errors introduced in iOS 7 that are really making Cordova development a headache for me, so Apple probably doesn't test Cordova apps at all. Wishful thinking I guess.

Comment: Probably :) Doesn't surprise me at all — it's natural they want to push for fully native apps to differentiate from competitor OSes. I don't think they really care about Cordova one bit. But bugs with Cordova apps are bugs with WebKit, and those do get (eventually) fixed.

Answer (score 7):

A plain cordova sample app (e.g. "cordova create test") will load fine.

If you add any cordova plugins you will encounter problems in "iOSExec()", see "platform_www/cordova.js":

```
bridgeMode = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' 5_') == -1 ? jsToNativeModes.IFRAME_NAV: jsToNativeModes.XHR_NO_PAYLOAD;
```

Change that to:

```
bridgeMode = jsToNativeModes.IFRAME_NAV;
```

and you can use plugins again. This will break backwards compatibility with iOS 5, but i doubt you will find anybody running iOS 5 and cordova today...

If you are using fastclick.js or backbone.js you will have to make some small modifications, too.
Just follow the error messages in Safari's webinspector.

Comment: What changes have to be done in backbone and fast click ? Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Update XCode to Beta 2 and it's working without any fix (tested with cordova 3.5.0).

You need to download the new version of XCode on the iOS Dev Center since autoupdate is not yet available for beta..