# Is Phone-gap apps(ios-7) will run on ios-8 or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ios8

I want to know if I will update my iphone from ios 7 to ios 8 then, those application which are developed by cross platform technologies (Phone-gap / titanium ) will run on ios 8 or not?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cd02c73162180793513e#file-ios8-beta-phonegap-fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Refer this Code On your Html script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(!navigator.userAgent) navigator.userAgent = "User Agent String :: mozilla/5.0 (iphone;     cpu iphone os 8_0_0 like mac os x) applewebkit/537.51.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/8.0 mobile/11a501 safari/9537.53";
 </script>
```

So your iOS 7 phone gap apps will not on IOS 8 because User agent is changed in ios8
if apple release original version of xcode then may be fixed this issue

Answer (score 1):

There are issues related to phonegap apps being broken in iOS 8 due to some issues related to user agent. You can expect bug fixes in future releases.

So your iOS 7 phonegap apps **won't** run on iOS 8 until the bug is fixed, maybe in future releases.

Community has also suggested this [fix](https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cd02c73162180793513e#file-ios8-beta-phonegap-fix).

You can refer this post: [Phonegap / Cordova not working in ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008307/phonegap-cordova-not-working-in-ios8)